# Changing visible LinkButton with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

[EXPLANATION] *(sorry that its really long)*

I have a gridview where the user is allowed to add an entry or edit an existing entry. When clicking on either option ('Add' or 'Edit'), a popup window will appear for the user to set the new/existing item's information.

Since the two popups would be identical (other than the text fields in the edit popup being populated with editable data) I decided to make just one popup, with two different LinkButtons (one that, when clicked, Adds a new record, while the other saves the changes made to the current record)

I do however, need to make only one of these links visible at a time, depending upon what action the user has taken ('Add' or 'Edit'). For the add button, since its just opening a blank popup, I don't want it to go to codebehind, so I'm using jQuery to set the display of the 'Edit' save button to none, and it works fine.

However, since the 'Add' button doesn't activate codebehind, I can't set its visibility to false in codebehind when I click the 'Edit' button, because then clicking the 'Add' button doesn't set it to true, so I need to use jQuery when the 'Edit' button is clicked to flip-flop the visibilities again.

[QUESTION]

My problem is, while this approach works for when the user clicks the 'Add' button, it doesn't hide the 'Add'-'Save' link when the user clicks 'Edit'? It does set the `display:inline;` for the 'Edit'-'Save' button however, which is why I find this so peculiar. I used Chrome's debugger and it is getting there, so can anyone tell me whats wrong?

[CODE]

.aspx

```
<%-- the edit button, located within a gridview --%>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="showEditLink();" Text="Edit" CommandName="editCmd" CommandArgument='<%# ... %>'></asp:LinkButton> 

<%-- the add button, located underneath the gridview --%>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddCert" runat="server" Text="Add Certification" OnClientClick="javascript:showAddLink(); return false;" />

<%-- the 'save' buttons, located within an ASPxPopupControl (DevExpress) --%>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddSave" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Save" OnClick="lbAddSave_Click" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditSave" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Save" OnClick="lbEditSave_Click" />
```

jQuery

```
function showAddLink() {
        $("[id*='_lbEditSave']").css('display', 'none');
        $("[id*='_lbAddSave']").css('display', 'inline');
        pcPopup.Show();
        return false;
    }

    function showEditLink() {
        $("[id*='_lbEditSave']").css('display', 'inline');
        $("[id*='_lbAddSave']").css('display', 'none');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just have one button, and set the text and the onClick based on whether the user was adding/editing. Something like this in your javascript for the add case:

```
function setUpForAdd() {
  var button = $('#buttonID');
  button.html('Add button text')
  button.click(addHandlerFunction);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with javascript? Or with some other non-postback method?

Comment: this isn't working. I'm pretty sure its because since my LinkButtons are ASP.NET controls, their onclick events are different than a typical onclick event. I'm sure there is a way to use basic javascript functions to do 'Ajax' callbacks and use *those* as the event handlers...I'm just hoping for an easier solution than that

Comment: I confess I don't use ASP.NET controls. I'd just use anchors and style them with CSS.

Comment: Thats fine. I just need to be able call C# functions from my codebehind. I know its possible with javascript, so I'm going to try and do something like that with what you're suggesting